# Why is my catch statement triggering even though the .then is resolved?

Tags: javascript, express, axios

This is the code I have currently in my server folder. I was just wondering for some reason the catch console log is still sending even though the .then statement actively sends a response though res.send works and sends a response to the user?

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { API_KEY, API_URL } = process.env
const axios = require("axios")

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(API_URL + API_KEY)
    await axios.get(API_URL + API_KEY + "&count=9")
        .then((response) => {
            res.send(response.data)
        })
        .catch(
            console.log("error")
        )
})

module.exports = router
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`.catch` accepts a *callback* - right now, you're invoking `console.log` immediately and passing the result to `.catch`. This:

```
// ...
.catch(console.log("error"))
```

is equivalent to

```
const consoleResult = console.log("error");
// ...
.catch(consoleResult)
```

You need to change to

```
.catch(
    () => {
        console.log("error")
    }
)
```

Or, even better, examine the argument to see what the error was:

```
.catch(
    (error) => {
        console.log("error:", error.message)
    }
)
```

Comment: OH, got it thank you :)